# Can I use the cocos2d-x scheduler to delay a single line of code?

Tags: c++, timer, cocos2d-x, sleep, schedule

I'm essentially trying to delay a modification on an object by 10 seconds.

This is what I thought might work:

```
this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(customer->setBusy(false)), 10000);
```

But I get a compiler error:

```
Lvalue required as unary '&' operand
```

Is there a simple way to delay a line of code? Maybe just using a c++ command would be more efficient, but the `sleep` command is giving me issues as well.

Answer (score 5):

You need to write you schedularOnce like this

In .h file you declare

```
void myModification(float dt);
```

In .cpp file

```
this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(&MyClass::myModification), 10.0f);

void Myclass::myModification(float dt)
{
//your code
}
```

ALL These are in cocos2d-x 2.2

Comment: It doesn't work. callback function is not called after an interval.

Comment: What is there for 3.xx ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make a function out of that single line of code because you can't pass values to a selector function.  So something like this:

```
this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(MyClass::myModification), 10.0f);
```

Then you would have a function with the modification code in it.

```
void MyClass::myModification(float dt)
{
    customer->setBusy(false);
    // Whatever other stuff you want run.
}
```

Also, the delay at the end is measured in seconds, not milliseconds.  So you would have been waiting a few hours for this to run.

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this by creating a callback and calling it from within a sequence if your class derives from Node. This is a useful pattern if you need to create chains of actions or synchronize game events with action sequences. (Cocos version 3+)

```
const float myDelay = 1.0f;
this->runAction( Sequence::create(
                                  DelayTime::create(myDelay),
                                  CallFunc::create(CC_CALLBACK_0(MyClass::MyFunction, this)),
                                  nullptr));
```

Answer (score 0):

this->scheduleOnce it only can use itself method